# How to Shorten If Statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have if statements that are checking to see if the var matches certain text and then update a href if they do. I feel like I should be able to make this shorter instead of checking it this way. I realize an array could solve this I'm not sure how that would work in this case however. Thank you for any help! :)

The variables look like this:

```
var rank1 = $('#jobRank1').html()
var rank2 = $('#jobRank2').html()
var rank3 = $('#jobRank3').html()
var rank4 = $('#jobRank4').html()
var rank5 = $('#jobRank5').html()
```

The If statements look like this:

```
if(rank1 == "Entrepreneur (Business Owner)"){
    ('#jobRank1').attr("href", "/entrepreneur")
}

if(rank2 == "Entrepreneur (Business Owner)"){
    ('#jobRank2').attr("href", "/entrepreneur")
}

if(rank3 == "Entrepreneur (Business Owner)"){
    ('#jobRank3').attr("href", "/entrepreneur")
}

if(rank4 == "Entrepreneur (Business Owner)"){
    ('#jobRank4').attr("href", "/entrepreneur")
}

if(rank5 == "Entrepreneur (Business Owner)"){
    ('#jobRank5').attr("href", "/entrepreneur")
}
```

Comment: 2 things: Arrays and loops.

Comment: `range(1, 5).map(i => \`#jobRank${i}\`).forEach(jr => $(jr).html() === "Entr..." ? $(jr).attr(...))`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is asking for a code review to make logic better, not to solve a problem.  As such it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Taplar, is there anything that says that this sort of refactoring is out-of-bounds here?  I think of codereview as more specifically about actually reviewing the user's code than refactoring and/or rewriting it.

Comment: @ScottSauyet If you read the how to ask documentation it talks entirely about how to express to the community what your problem is.  Making code better isn't a problem.  It's refactoring, which is the entire point of the existence of the codereview site.

Comment: @Taplar: I guess I see it differently.  Making code better is one of the most important sort of programming problems.  I did reread the on-topic and off-topic documents, and came away with a different impression, so I was wondering if you had some explicit reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will do the job:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
    let el = $('#jobRank' + i);
    if (el.html() === 'Entrepreneur (Business Owner)') {
        el.attr('href', '/entrepreneur');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Evan this is exactly what I was trying to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  .map(i => $(`#jobRank${i}`))
  .filter($rank => $rank.html() == "Entrepreneur (Business Owner)")
  .forEach($rank => $rank.attr('href', '/entrepeneur'))
```

And if I had a `range` function handy, I might replace `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` with `range(1, 6)`, or `range(1, 5)`, however it worked.

Comment: You should have a look at Clojure(Script) :)

Comment: @slipset: I'm actually one of the primary authors of the JS functional programming library [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com).  I'm familiar with ClojureScript, Elm, and PureScript as interesting alternatives to JS, although I don't use them much.

Comment: Ramda looks nice. Like the auto-currying!

Answer (score 2):

A slightly functional way of doing it

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
.map(i => $('#jobRank' + i))
.filter(el => el && el.html() === 'Entrepreneur (Business Owner)')
.forEach(el => el.attr('href', '/entrepreneur'))
```

Comment: Beat you to it.  ;-)

Comment: I see that, but I belive your code will fail with a null pointer if one of the #jobRange thingies is not present.

Comment: I'm assuming that jQuery will take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using jquery

```
$("[id^='jobRank']").filter(function(index)
    {return $(this).html()==="Entrepreneur (Business Owner)"})
    .attr("href", "/entrepreneur");
```

One statement, that's it.

What this does is select all elements with an Id that starts with jobRank, then performs an additional [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) based on the html of the element.

Demo:

```js
$("[id^='jobRank']").filter(function(index){
    return $(this).html()==="Entrepreneur (Business Owner)";})
    .attr("href", "/entrepreneur")
    .addClass("entrpreneur");
```

```css
.entrpreneur {font-weight:bold;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id='jobRank1' href="#")>Entrepreneur (Business Owner)<a>
<a id='jobRank2' href="#")>Bob<a>
<a id='jobRank3' href="#")>Brian<a>
<a id='jobRank4' href="#")>Entrepreneur (Business Owner)<a>
<a id='jobRank5' href="#")>Entrepreneur (Business Owner)<a>
```

Comment: This is awesome.

Comment: I had to fo a slight bug fix to the filter. `This` needed to be cast to a jQueryObject.

Answer (score 0):

you can use switch instead of if

```
switch(expression) {
    case n:
        code block
        break;
    case n:
        code block
        break;
    default:
        code block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

condition? true:false

1. condition : your condition.
2. true : what to do in case condition returns TRUE
3. false : what to do in cast condition returns FALSE

   rank1 == "Entrepreneur (Business Owner)"? ('#jobRank1').attr("href", "/entrepreneur"):return

Answer (score 0):

You can use [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function to execute a function through an array. At the same time, you can recover array element `rank` and its index `i`. Notice that i start counting on `0`, as the rank start at `1`, so the need of summing `i+1`.

```
[
  rank1,
  rank2,
  rank3,
  rank4
].forEach(
  function(rank, i) {
    if(rank == "Entrepreneur (Business Owner)")
      $("#jobRank" + (i+1)).("href", "/entrepreneur");
  });
```